# how to extract the first element of each tuple in each sublist?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and within each sublist there are tuples with the format (iD, volume).  I need to keep the first element of each tuple and do away with the second while saving the new list of lists into `binContents`.

for example:

```
bins = [[(2, 22), (1, 13)], [(2, 22)], [(0, 20)]]
binContents =
```

Desired outcome:

```
print(binContents)
[[2,1],[2],[0]]
```

*not a duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) because I do not intend on making a flat list, and that code with additional indexing did not give me my desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go:

```
bins = [[(2, 22), (1, 13)], [(2, 22)], [(0, 20)]]
binContents = [[y[0] for y in x] for x in bins]
print(binContents)
```

This yields

```
[[2, 1], [2], [0]]
```